# UWP remove PasswordVault entries when uninstall the app

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

We have actually an application running under UWP. We were investigate some security issues related to the application: we are storing sensible data into the Credential Locker using `PasswordVault`. The issue is : when we uninstall the app, the data still persist on the app and we want to remove it whenever the app is uninstalled.

We tried to use :

- PackageUninstalling to detect the event, but what happen when the app is not running ?
- We have investigate Desktop6 but looks like it is related to Games

We expect a solution to remove these sensible data during the uninstallation process

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry, UWP currently cannot monitor its own uninstall event outside of its process.**

If you do want this feature, I'd suggest you submit a feature request about this feature in the Feedback Hub. You could find the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu.

Please select **Developer Platform**-> **API Feedback** as the category when you submit your request. The related team will check the request.